# How to just Count the last result

Tags: postgresql, grafana, psql

Im trying to show a Count of the tickets responded by my team and somehow in the codeing it is not just showing of the last "updated_on" by that person, sometime it shows more than an "updated_on" or other cases it shows the "updated_on" but the ticket was not solve trully by him.
My final goal with this was just a dashboard in grafana here it shows all the tickets each member of my team has responded.

My Code:

```
Select vgtuser, count(*)
From (
SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.ticket_id) a.ticket_id, max(a.updated_on), b.name as vgtuser 
FROM ticket_messages a
INNER JOIN admins b ON a.admin_id=b.admin_id
INNER JOIN ticket_status_history c ON a.ticket_id=c.ticket_id
WHERE c.status_id IN(50, 60, 65) AND a.updated_by LIKE 'Ana Monteiro' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno Gonçalves' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Henrique Espinha' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Ricardo Sousa' or a.updated_by LIKE 'João Fernandes' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Pedro Pereira' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Luis Moreno' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Gonçalo Rodrigues' or a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno Coelho'
GROUP BY a.ticket_id, b.name
) as media
group by 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: You need to put parentheses around the `a.updated_by LIKE '...' or a.updated_by LIKE '...'` .

Comment: What do you mean, like a.updated_by LIKE('. . .') or (a.updated_by LIKE '. . .' OR  a.updated_by LIKE '. . .')

Comment: No, AND operator has precedence over the OR operator. Writing `c.status_id IN(50, 60, 65) AND a.updated_by LIKE 'Ana' OR a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno'` is like writing `(c.status_id IN (50,60,65) AND a.updated_by LIKE 'Ana') OR (a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno'`)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Altered Query**  :

```
Select vgtuser,max(updt), count(*)
From (

SELECT DISTINCT ON(a.updated_on) a.ticket_id, max(a.updated_on) as updt, b.name as vgtuser 
FROM ticket_messages a
INNER JOIN admins b ON a.admin_id=b.admin_id
INNER JOIN ticket_status_history c ON a.ticket_id=c.ticket_id
WHERE c.status_id IN(50, 60, 65) AND (
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Ana Monteiro' or 
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno Gonçalves' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Henrique Espinha' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Ricardo Sousa' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'João Fernandes' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Pedro Pereira' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Luis Moreno' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Gonçalo Rodrigues' or
 a.updated_by LIKE 'Nuno Coelho')
GROUP BY a.ticket_id, b.name,a.updated_on

) as media
group by 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

if you change the order at the end of the query you will not get the latest updated on , you will get the most updated by.

Comment: it dosnt work, and i dont want to see the last results(sorry if i was miss leading to that), i want it to just "select" them so i can after count and them i get the exact number of tickets each member of my team has responded